# Difference between の間で and 間で?

Tags: grammar

These two sentences seem to use the same pattern, yet differently:

> 親族**間で**複雑な対立関係がある。
>
> 使用人たち**の間で**も、そう囁かれています。

I found that 間 could mean ''among'' in this case, but what is the difference between the first usage of 間 and the second? I also presume that in the first sentence, 間 is read 'かん', isn't it?

Would 親族の間で and 使用人間で work as well?

Comment: 人間｛にんげん｝couldn't be substituted for 人の間.

Comment: Additional hint: many kanji have multiple readings, and certain readings are only used in certain contexts.  See [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%96%93#Japanese), among other resources: the version of 間 that attaches directly to kanji-compound nouns is not the same 間 that's used as a standalone noun.

Comment: I don't understand. 親族 is the noun. It doesn't seem wrong to me to add の間で right after. Don't we also say 友達の間で? What's different?

Comment: @Ushiromiya, the difference is the lack of the の.  親族【しんぞく】間【かん】 has a different reading, and slightly different nuance, from 親族【しんぞく】の間【あいだ】.  Note also that 親族【しんぞく】 is read with the _on'yomi_, while 友達【ともだち】 is read with the _kun'yomi_.  The reading also has an impact on the kinds of things that can compound with a noun.

Comment: I figured that much, but I'm asking about the difference in meaning between adding 間で after a noun, and using the form の間で. Also, adding 間で after a noun doesn't seem to work all the time, in which case I'd like to know  the prerequisite to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to me the meaning of the two expressions would be quite the same, but I think some words don’t fit well in the expression “〜間(kan)”.

- I suspect 和語 will generally fit well with “〜の間(aida)”
  △:人々間(Hitobito kan)
  ○:人々の間
- I suspect “〜間(kan)” is used rather for a fixed expression
  Ex. 国家間、学校間、友人間

My advice is:

If you are not sure which to use, use “〜の間（aida）”, then you will be on the safe side. I can’t come up with an example you can’t use this expression when you can use “〜間(kan)”.
(Maybe it is partly because, “kan” has a lot of
expressions with the same pronunciation, so “Aida” is preferred generally)

If you wish to make the expression shorter, use “〜間(kan)”.

Anyhow, I think you just need to know there are practically no differences in meaning. (Although there might be some exception I can’t come up with right now.)